# Recommended practice for deploying AWS CDKV2.0 stacks with complex lambdas through ADF

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cdk

Our team has decided to adopt the AWS CDKV2.0 to build and manage our AWS resources. We are also using The AWS Deployment Framework to manage the deployment process by creating Code Pipelines and using AWS Code build.

The Setup we currently have works for the most part. We seem to have stumbled upon an issue when we attempt to deploy any of our resource that contain assets such as lambdas. Specifically I am talking about lambdas which **are not included in-line** within the synthezied cloudformation template as [per this example](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-deployment-framework/blob/master/samples/sample-cdk-app/index.ts#L13).

In other words our lambda code is expected to be uploaded to S3 before being deployed,I am looking for best practice guides on how to configure our accounts and ADF with the CDK to deploy assets which require uploading to S3. At the moment all I can think of is either Bootstrapping the accounts we deploy to and/or customising the CDK synthesizer as part of our stack definition, any guidance or thoughts would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

> In other words our lambda code is expected to be uploaded to S3 before being deployed

Luckily, no. The CDK's lambda constructs automagically handle [local asset bundling and S3 uploading out of the box](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_lambda-readme.html).  The CDK also accepts inline code an existing S3 buckets as code sources. And Docker images.

```js
// aws_cdk.aws_lambda
const fn = new lambda.Function(this, 'MyFunction', {
  runtime: lambda.Runtime.NODEJS_12_X,
  handler: 'index.handler',
  code: lambda.Code.fromAsset(path.join(__dirname, 'lambda-handler')),
});
```

Even better, the CDK provides runtime-specific lambda constructs (in dedicated modules) to make life even easier.  For instance, CDK will transpile your `ts` or build your `go` executable for you and send the artifacts to a CDK-managed S3 bucket on `cdk deploy`.

```js
// aws_cdk.aws_lambda_nodejs
new NodejsFunction(this, 'MyFunction', {
  entry: '/path/to/my/file.ts', // accepts .js, .jsx, .ts and .tsx files
  handler: 'myExportedFunc', // defaults to 'handler'
});

// aws_cdk.aws_lambda_go_alpha
new GoFunction(this, 'handler', {
  entry: 'app/cmd/api',
});

// aws_cdk.aws_lambda_python_alpha
new PythonFunction(this, 'MyFunction', {
  entry: '/path/to/my/function', // required
  runtime: Runtime.PYTHON_3_8, // required
  index: 'my_index.py', // optional, defaults to 'index.py'
  handler: 'my_exported_func', // optional, defaults to 'handler'
});
```